# Passing variables between controllers and returning (PHP)

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

Probably is a very easy question, but I'm new and after trying to find a similar I'm still unsure:

So I have an AJAX form pointing to:

```
function postLogin(Request $request){
   $this->fatherAuth($request); 

   return response() -> json(['url' => '/login-ok',], 200); 
}
```

Then I have:

```
public function fatherAuth($request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ],[
         'email.required' => 'Email needed',
    ]);

    # do some other checks and if there's some auth error:# 
    return response() -> json(['url' => '/login-bad',], 400); 
}
```

So what's happening is that I'm always getting the 200 response instead of the 400.

Should I pass a variable to postLogin? Should I send it to a new function?

BTW the reason of creating fatherAuth is because this code is shared between several controllers.

What would be the best solution / best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `200 response` because you are not doing anything with response returned by `fatherAuth` method.

To make it work you should use something like:

```
function postLogin(Request $request){
   $response = $this->fatherAuth($request); 

   if ($response instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Response) {
       return $response;
   }

   return response() -> json(['url' => '/login-ok',], 200); 
}
```

but as you see it wouldn't be the best approach.

That's why you should use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#introduction) for this. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // here you do anything you want and assign to $result variable
        if (!$result) {
            return response() -> json(['url' => '/login-bad',], 400); 
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and then you can apply this middleware to all the routes adding to `$middleware` array in `App/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
App\Http\Middleware\CheckAuth::class,
```

Of course you can apply this middleware only to selected routes if you need.

After that in your `postLogin` method it's enough to have only:

```
function postLogin(Request $request){
   return response() -> json(['url' => '/login-ok',], 200); 
}
```

Comment: oh, thank you very much! So I went option 1 because it was much more easy haha I just changed ...instanceof.. to if ($response) {return $response;}else {200}